# How to join three tables with a NOT IN CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Scenario ... A STORE gets a LIST. The 'LIST' basically is a collection of SKUs that the store stocks that needs to be counted.

When a store starts counting the SKUs from a given List assigned to it, the information is saved in another table called 'StoreCycles' which records the ListId, StoreName and the Dates the counting started and completed.

These are my tables.

Table 1. Table with 'Lists' which have a primary key 'ListId'

```
ListId ListName  
   1       abc
   2       def
   3       ghi
```

Table 2. 'Stores' -- Each list from the above table ('Lists' Table) is assigned to one or more stores. 
The ListId in the 'Stores' Table is the primary key of the 'Lists' tabel. The Listid and LineId together make up the foreign key.

```
ListId LineId StoreName
  1       1    StoreA
  1       2    StoreD
  2       1    StoreB
  2       2    StoreC
  2       3    StoreA
  3       1    StoreA
```

Table 3. 'StoreCycles'  -- that saves when the list assigned to a store was started counting and when it was completed.

```
ListId  StoreName  StartDate   CompleteDate
  1      StoreA   2016-7-22    2016-7-22
  2      StoreA   2016-7-22
  2      StoreC   2016-7-22
```

At any time I want to pull up those list names that have not been completed , i.e they have a null complete date.

This is my query:

```
Select  T0.ListId,
T0.ListNaame  ,
T2.StartDate   
From    Lists T0
JOIN    Stores T1   On  T0.ListId  = T1.ListId 
LEFT JOIN StoreCycles T2   ON  T0.ListId  = T2.ListId
WHERE T1.StoreName = 'StoreA'
AND T0.ListId  NOT IN (SELECT ListId FROM StoreCycles WHERE CompleteDate IS NOT NULL)
```

RESULT SHOULD BE >>

```
ListId ListName StartDate
  2      def      2016-7-22
  3      ghi      NULL
```

BUT The result that I get is this

```
ListId ListName StartDate
 2      def        NULL
 2      def        NULL
 3      ghi        NULL
```

Comment: You have the field `ListName` in your result set as an integer but your data shows the same field to be a string (`abc`). Please correct your question to show what you would like to be the result of your query: `LineId` or `ListName`

Comment: I tried your query and it gives the result it should be. At least if CompleteDate is a date field. Can you check if CompleteDate isn't some varchar with spaces where there should be null's?

Comment: I've also tried your query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/913ce/2) and it gives the result similar to what you expect - although the list _name_ is different to the _id_ you give in your example.

Comment: @Tony thank you for pointing it out. Appreciate it.

Comment: I did not frame my last table correctly. My bad. My sincere apologies if I have wasted your time. Looks like I am a bit stressed out after a days work on the job. I have edited to make it right this time. The last table does not have a field called 'LineId'

Comment: @Harrobbed - Don't worry, SO is there for when you get stressed. Do you still have a question to answer or have you solved your problem?

Comment: @Tony I have edited the sqlfiddle provided by LukStorms. The problem is when the table 'StoreCycles' have one more entry for the same ListId but assigned to a different Store. the query result pulls out records for both the stores even when you specify StoreName. I have edited my question above again. Please reflect. Applologies. I am not a SQL guy.

Comment: @Harrobbed I don't think you wasted our time and your query may give your desired results but there is no need for the select in the where clause because you already have the table joined so performance wise it would be better to use your joins than another select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just passing by and dumping SQL.

Go on, nothing to see.

There is no bug hunt going on here.

```sql
declare @Lists table (ListId int primary key, ListName varchar(20));
insert into @lists values (1,'abc'),(2,'def'),(3,'ghi');

declare @Stores table (ListId int, LineId int, StoreName varchar(20));
insert into @Stores values 
(1,1,'StoreA'),
(1,2,'StoreD'),
(2,1,'StoreB'),
(2,2,'StoreC'),
(2,3,'StoreA'),
(3,1,'StoreA');

declare @StoreCycles table (ListId int, StoreName varchar(20), StartDate date, CompleteDate date);
insert into @StoreCycles values
(1,'StoreA','2016-7-22','2016-7-22'),
(2,'StoreA','2016-7-22',null),
(2,'StoreC','2016-7-22',null);

SELECT
L.ListId,
L.ListName,
SC.StartDate
FROM @Stores S   
JOIN @Lists L On (S.ListId  = L.ListId)
LEFT JOIN @StoreCycles SC ON (S.ListId  = SC.ListId AND S.StoreName = SC.StoreName)
WHERE S.StoreName = 'StoreA' 
AND SC.CompleteDate IS NULL;
```

Comment: I have edited your fiddle here [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddf001/1)  if you notice the result retrieves two entries for ListId referring to ListId '2' which is assigned to both store StoreA and StoreC. I only want to pull results for a specific store.

Comment: This time I added Storename to the 2nd join. Gets the expected result.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I really need to hone my sql skills. Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me out even though I did not frame the question properly, the first time.

Comment: Btw, I noticed that you used the SQL fiddle for MySQL to test. But that site also has a 2 fiddles for SQL Server. For example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6).  But I tested it on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) which is sometimes quicker when you only use table variables to test your code since it doesn't require to build a schema.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another way to look at it is to return all rows where either the `StartDate` is NULL (no records) or the `CompleteDate` is NULL (incomplete records). Also, if the foreign key is using 2 columns you probably want to use both columns in the JOIN.

```
SELECT  T0.ListId,
        T0.ListName,
        T2.StartDate
FROM    Lists T0
            JOIN Stores T1   
                 ON T1.ListId = T0.ListId
            LEFT JOIN StoreCycles T2
                 ON T2.ListId = T1.ListId
                AND T2.LineId = T1.LineId
WHERE T1.StoreName = 'StoreA'
AND (T2.CompleteDate IS NULL OR T2.StartDate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    l.ListId
    ,l.ListNaame 
    ,sc.StartDate
From
    Lists l
    JOIN Stores s
    ON  l.ListId  = s.ListId
    AND s.StoreName = 'StoreA' 
        LEFT JOIN StoreCycles sc 
        ON  s.ListId  = sc.ListId
        AND s.LineId = sc.LineId
WHERE
      sc.CompleteDate IS NULL
```

You are already doing joins if you build them correctly you will not need a select or not in in your where clause.  Also your relationship for `StoreCycles` seems to be wrong because you are trying to go straight from `Lists` to `StoreCycles` but `Stores` is the intermediary table.

Also just a thought why not use table aliases that will help you know what table you are referring to rather than t0, t1, t2 such as l, s, sc....